# Taking Refuge in the Dhamma

Tags: theravada, reference-request, pali-canon, sutras

**Friends**, having heard in many a Dhamma talk references being made to the permanence of the Dhamma as refuge, I am looking for suttas in the Pali Canon evoking that very theme of permanence of the Dhamma.

Thank you for your much appreciated help.

Comment: Related Thig 13:1  Ambapālī https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/KN/Thig/thig13_1.html

Comment: The Pali here for "doesn’t change" is anaññathā, which appears to not mean "permanence": https://suttacentral.net/define/ana%C3%B1%C3%B1ath%C4%81

Answer (score 3):

The Dhamma is described as timeless (akāliko).

From the [Pali glossary](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/glossary.html):

> akāliko:
>       Timeless; unconditioned by time or season.

From [SN 55.22](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn55/sn55.022.than.html):

> "He/she is endowed with verified confidence in the Dhamma: 'The Dhamma
>   is well-expounded by the Blessed One, to be seen here & now, **timeless**,
>   inviting verification, pertinent, to be realized by the wise for
>   themselves.'

From [AN 6.47](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.047.than.html):

> "... the Dhamma is visible in the here-&-now, **timeless**, inviting
>   verification, pertinent, to be realized by the wise for themselves."

From [AN 3.40](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.040.than.html):

> Now, the Dhamma is well-taught by the Blessed One, to be seen here &
>   now, **timeless**, inviting all to come & see, pertinent, to be seen
>   by the wise for themselves. There are fellow practitioners of the
>   chaste life who dwell knowing & seeing it.

You can also find this in AN 11.11, AN 11.12, AN 5.179, AN 10.92 and AN 3.70.

From [this essay](http://www.buddhanet.net/nowknow1.htm) by Ajahn Sumedo:

> The second refuge is in the Dhamma, in ultimate truth or ultimate
>   reality. Dhamma is impersonal; we don’t in any way try to personify it
>   to make it any kind of personal deity. When we chant in Pali the verse
>   on Dhamma, we say it is ‘*sanditthiko akaliko ehipassiko opanayiko
>   paccattam veditabbo vinnuhi*’. As Dhamma has no personal attributes, we
>   can’t even say it is good or bad or anything that has any superlative
>   or comparative quality; it is beyond the dualistic conceptions of
>   mind.
>
> So when we describe Dhamma or give an impression of it, we do it
>   through words such as ‘*sanditthiko*’, which means immanent,
>   here-and-now. That brings us back into the present; we feel a sense of
>   immediacy, of now. You may think that Dhamma is some kind of thing
>   that is ‘out there’, something you have to find elsewhere, but
>   *sanditthikodhamma* means that it is immanent, here-and-now.
>
> ***Akalikadhamma* means that Dhamma is not bound by any time condition.
>   The word *akala* means timeless. Our conceptual mind can’t conceive of
>   anything that is timeless, because our conceptions and perceptions are
>   time-based conditions, but what we can say is that Dhamma is akala,
>   not bound by time.**
>
> *Ehipassikadhamma* means to come and see, to turn towards or go to the
>   Dhamma. It means to look, to be aware. It is not that we pray to the
>   Dhamma to come, or wait for it to tap us on the shoulder; we have to
>   put forth effort. It is like Christ’s saying, ‘Knock on the door and
>   it shall be opened.’ *Ehipassiko* means that we have to put forward that
>   effort, to turn towards that truth.
>
> *Opanayiko* means leading inwards, towards the peace within the mind.
>   Dhamma doesn’t take us into fascination, into excitement, romance and
>   adventure, but leads to Nibbana, to calm, to silence.
>
> *Paccattam veditabbo vinnuhi* means that we can only know Dhamma through
>   direct experience. It is like the taste of honey — if someone else
>   tastes it, we still don’t know its flavour. We may know the chemical
>   formula or be able to recite all the great poetry ever written about
>   honey, but only when we taste it for ourselves do we really know what
>   it is like. It is the same with Dhamma: we have to taste it, we have
>   to know it directly.
>
> Taking refuge in Dhamma is taking another safe refuge. It is not
>   taking refuge in philosophy or intellectual concepts, in theories, in
>   ideas, in doctrines or beliefs of any sort. It is not taking refuge in
>   a belief in Dhamma, or a belief in God or in some kind of force in
>   outer space or something beyond or something separate, something that
>   we have to find sometime later. The descriptions of the Dhamma keep us
>   in the present, in the here-and-now, unbound by time. Taking refuge is
>   an immediate immanent reflection in the mind, it is not just repeating
>   ‘*Dhammam Saranam gacchami*’ like a parrot, thinking, ‘Buddhists say
>   this so I have to say it.’ We turn towards the Dhamma, we are aware
>   now, take refuge in Dhamma, now as an immediate action, an immediate
>   reflection of being the Dhamma, being that very truth.

Comment: I think akāliko means "immediately effective" or "without delay" rather than the "timelessness" inferred in this post. It means as soon as dhamma is practised (example, craving & attachment are abandoned), the result is immediate (example, liberation from dukkha).

Comment: Thanks for your taking the time anf effort to write down such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following phrase about the permanence of the Dhamma Law (Natural Truth) is found in both [AN 3.136](https://suttacentral.net/en/an3.136) and [SN 12.20](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.020.than.html).

> *Monks, whether or not there is the arising of Tathagatas, this property stands — this steadfastness of the Dhamma, this orderliness of
>   the Dhamma.*